# Why are li's not showing up with python requests response?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a homework project with web scraping and am suppose to collect all the even information for a month from a school website. I am using Python with Requests and Beautiful Soup. I have written some code to grab a url and am trying to grab all of the li's from the page that hold the event information. However, when I go to grab all of the li content I noticed that I am not receiving all of them. I have been thinking it is due to the style of "overflow:hidden" for the ul but why am I able to get the first few li's then?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://apps.iu.edu/ccl-prd/events/view?date=06012016&type=day&pubCalId=GRP1322'
r = requests.get(url)
bsObj =  BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")    

eventList = []
eventURLs = bsObj.find_all("a",href=True)
print len(eventURLs)

count = 1
for url in eventURLs:
    print str(count) + '. ' + url['href']
    count += 1
```

I am printing out the urls because I plan on going to the href link inside of the events to get the full descriptions and other metadata provided. However, I am not getting all of the event lis. I am only getting the first 5. The links in the output that I get that are for the events are numbers 19 to 23. The page has 10 total events though.

output:

```
1. https://www.indiana.edu/
2. #advancedSearch
3. /ccl-prd/events/view?type=week&date=06012016&pubCalId=GRP1322
4. /ccl-prd/events/view?type=month&date=06012016&pubCalId=GRP1322
5. /ccl-prd/events/view?type=day&date=06222016&pubCalId=GRP1322
6. /ccl-prd/events/view?pubCalId=GRP1432&type=day&date=06012016
7. /ccl-prd/events/view?pubCalId=GRP1445&type=day&date=06012016
8. /ccl-prd/events/view?pubCalId=GRP1436&type=day&date=06012016
9. /ccl-prd/events/view?pubCalId=GRP1438&type=day&date=06012016
10. /ccl-prd/events/view?pubCalId=GRP1440&type=day&date=06012016
11. /ccl-prd/events/view?pubCalId=GRP1443&type=day&date=06012016
12. /ccl-prd/events/view?pubCalId=GRP1434&type=day&date=06012016
13. /ccl-prd/events/view?pubCalId=GRP1447&type=day&date=06012016
14. /ccl-prd/events/view?pubCalId=GRP1450&type=day&date=06012016
15. http://newsinfo.iu.edu/
16. http://www.indiana.edu/~iuvis/
17. /ccl-prd/events/view?type=day&date=06012016&iub=BL011&pubCalId=GRP1322
18. /ccl-prd/events/view?type=day&date=06012016&iub=BL153&pubCalId=GRP1322
19. /ccl-prd/events/view/13147231?viewParams=%26type%3dday%26date%3d06012016&theDate=06222016&referrer=listView&pubCalId=GRP1322
20. /ccl-prd/events/view/13163329?viewParams=%26type%3dday%26date%3d06012016&referrer=listView&pubCalId=GRP1322
21. /ccl-prd/events/view/13163465?viewParams=%26type%3dday%26date%3d06012016&theDate=06222016&referrer=listView&pubCalId=GRP1322
22. /ccl-prd/events/view/13110443?viewParams=%26type%3dday%26date%3d06012016&theDate=06222016&referrer=listView&pubCalId=GRP1322
23. /ccl-prd/events/view/11744967?viewParams=%26type%3dday%26date%3d06012016&theDate=06222016&referrer=listView&pubCalId=GRP1322
24. http://www.iu.edu/copyright/index.shtml
25. http://www.iu.edu/
```

TLDR: I am not getting all the links from the lis on a page when I use Python requests and beautiful soup. Why am I not getting the links and is there a better way of going about this problem?

Edited to give answer: The links I needed were all being created with Javascript and since Requests and Beautiful soup do not run the Javascript I have instead moved to Selenium with PhantomJS. However, an answer below shows how to get the information created by Javascript by using parameters in Python Requests which is a perfect way of doing this!

Comment: My first guess was that they are inside an iframe, but they weren't. So there other options are: 1. they were generated with a script, 2. there is a problem in your code that I didn't see

Comment: Have you checked the source code of that page? How are those links presented in the code?

Comment: I have looked at the source code. They are al there. However, there is a ul element they are in that has a style of "overflow:hidden". I do not know if this plays a factor because I am getting some of the links. I also posted the link in the description.

Comment: If you check the page you will find some of the links are generated by javascript and to scrap this you will have to use scrapy or phantom.

Comment: So the links are being generated by javascript? Why would I be able to get a few of them then, and not all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the links are generated with js but you can get all the event data from the ten events in json format just using requests:

```
import requests

params = {"pageNum": "1",
          "date": "06012016",
          "type": "day",
          "isSearch": "false",
          "pubCalId": "GRP1322"}

r = requests.get("https://apps.iu.edu/ccl-prd/events/view/page", params=params)

for ev in r.json()["events"][0]["events"]:
    print ev
```

Which gives you:

```
{u'groupEvent': True, u'allDay': True, u'description': u'\n\tOnline processing is not available. Drop forms should be obtained from the student&#39;s school. Completed forms must be submitted for processing at Student Central on Union.\n\n\tDates and times are subject to change without notice. See the Official Calendar for more details.\n', u'startDate': u'12:00am', u'calendarName': None, u'recurDateUtc': None, u'imageId': None, u'privateAndViewing': False, u'imageEventId': None, u'going': False, u'location': u'', u'imageCampus': u'BL', u'summary': u'Summer 2016: Withdrawal with Grade of W or F for First Six Week classes', u'recurs': False, u'id': u'13139699'}
{u'groupEvent': True, u'allDay': False, u'description': u'\r\n\tFor freshman Theodore Dreiser in 1889, Indiana University served as fertile ground for his future literary endeavors, but to him &ldquo;the life of the town, the character of its people, the professors and the students, and the mechanism, politics, and social interests of the University body proper&rdquo; were far more influential. For generatio', u'startDate': u'8:00am', u'calendarName': None, u'recurDateUtc': 1464796800000, u'imageId': 125740, u'privateAndViewing': False, u'imageEventId': 13147231, u'going': False, u'location': u'', u'imageCampus': u'BL', u'summary': u'Exhibit: Student Reform Movements at IU', u'recurs': True, u'id': u'13147231'}
{u'groupEvent': True, u'allDay': False, u'description': u'\r\n\tJoin us for Traditional Arts Indiana&#39;s traveling Bicentennial exhibit,&nbsp;Indiana Folk Arts: 200 Years of Tradition and Innovation.&nbsp;Before the exhibit begins its travels across Indiana, the MMWC will present it to the IU Bloomington campus and local communities. The exhibit will be on display through July 29, 2016.\r\n', u'startDate': u'9:00am', u'calendarName': None, u'recurDateUtc': 1464800400000, u'imageId': 129351, u'privateAndViewing': False, u'imageEventId': 13163465, u'going': False, u'location': u'Mathers Museum of World Cultures, 416 N. Indiana Ave, Bloomington, IN', u'imageCampus': u'BL', u'summary': u'EXHIBIT: "Indiana Folk Arts: 200 Years of Tradition and Innovation"', u'recurs': True, u'id': u'13163465'}
{u'groupEvent': True, u'allDay': False, u'description': u'\r\n\tIn 1913, Joseph Dixon visited the Tuscarora Nation, the smallest of the Haudenosaunee (Iroquois) communities, located in western New York. Dixon photographed six individuals during his visit, and those images became part of the Wanamaker Collection of Native American photographs, now housed at the Mathers Museum of World Cultures. While reviewin', u'startDate': u'9:00am', u'calendarName': None, u'recurDateUtc': 1464800400000, u'imageId': 115080, u'privateAndViewing': False, u'imageEventId': 13110443, u'going': False, u'location': u'Mathers Museum of World Cultures, 416 N Indiana Ave, Bloomington, IN 47408', u'imageCampus': u'BL', u'summary': u'EXHIBIT: "Stirring the Pot: Bringing the Wanamakers Home"', u'recurs': True, u'id': u'13110443'}
{u'groupEvent': True, u'allDay': False, u'description': u'\r\n\t&quot;Cherokee Craft, 1973,&quot; at the Mathers Museum of World Cultures, presents a snapshot of craft production among the Eastern Band Cherokee at a key moment in both an ongoing Appalachian craft revival and the specific cultural and economic life of the Cherokee people in western North Carolina. The exhibition showcases basketry in three di', u'startDate': u'9:00am', u'calendarName': None, u'recurDateUtc': 1464800400000, u'imageId': 96460, u'privateAndViewing': False, u'imageEventId': 11744967, u'going': False, u'location': u'Mathers Museum of World Cultures, 416 N. Indiana Ave, Bloomington, IN', u'imageCampus': u'BL', u'summary': u'EXHIBIT:  "Cherokee Craft, 1973"', u'recurs': True, u'id': u'11744967'}
{u'groupEvent': True, u'allDay': False, u'description': u'\r\n\t&quot;MONSTERS!&quot; are extraordinary or unnatural beings that challenge the predictable fabric of everyday life. This exhibition looks at monsters from around the world, discovering who they are and what purposes they serve in various cultures, as different images of monstrousness emerge from the dark recesses of human imagination. The exhibi', u'startDate': u'9:00am', u'calendarName': None, u'recurDateUtc': 1464800400000, u'imageId': 109380, u'privateAndViewing': False, u'imageEventId': 13088883, u'going': False, u'location': u'Mathers Museum of World Cultures, 416 N. Indiana Ave, Bloomington, IN', u'imageCampus': u'BL', u'summary': u'EXHIBIT: "MONSTERS!\'', u'recurs': True, u'id': u'13088883'}
{u'groupEvent': True, u'allDay': False, u'description': u'\r\n\t&quot;Tools of Travel&quot; features objects that people in different times and places have used to transport themselves and their belongings, exploring the technology of travel (wagon, saddle, sled, and canoe) and how it is powered (horse, camel, dog, and human). The exhibit opens March 22,2016 and will be open through December 17, 2017.\r\n', u'startDate': u'9:00am', u'calendarName': None, u'recurDateUtc': 1464800400000, u'imageId': 129348, u'privateAndViewing': False, u'imageEventId': 13146383, u'going': False, u'location': u'Mathers Museum of World Cultures, 416 N. Indiana Ave, Bloomington, IN', u'imageCampus': u'BL', u'summary': u'EXHIBIT: "Tools of Travel"', u'recurs': True, u'id': u'13146383'}
{u'groupEvent': True, u'allDay': False, u'description': u'\r\n\t&quot;Thoughts, Things, and Theories...What Is Culture?&quot;&nbsp; at the Mathers Museum of World Cultures, examines the nature of culture through the exploration of cultural traditions surrounding life stages and universal needs.\r\n\r\n\t&nbsp;\r\n\r\n\tFree visitor parking is available by the Indiana Avenue lobby entrance. Metered parking is available', u'startDate': u'9:00am', u'calendarName': None, u'recurDateUtc': 1464800400000, u'imageId': 76320, u'privateAndViewing': False, u'imageEventId': 10124630, u'going': False, u'location': u'Mathers Museum of World Cultures, 416 N. Indiana Ave., Bloomington, IN', u'imageCampus': u'BL', u'summary': u'EXHIBIT: "Thoughts, Things, and Theories...What Is Culture?"', u'recurs': True, u'id': u'10124630'}
{u'groupEvent': True, u'allDay': False, u'description': u'\r\n\tNew Acquisitions: African American Art\r\n\r\n\tA group of local community, university, and business leaders, headed by Donald Griffin, Jr., broker/owner of Griffin Realty, has formed a coalition to help the IU Art Museum build its collection of works by African American artists. These first acquisitions of what is hoped will become an annual endeavo', u'startDate': u'10:00am', u'calendarName': None, u'recurDateUtc': 1464804000000, u'imageId': None, u'privateAndViewing': False, u'imageEventId': None, u'going': False, u'location': u'Art Museum', u'imageCampus': u'BL', u'summary': u'New in the Galleries', u'recurs': True, u'id': u'13164911'}
{u'groupEvent': True, u'allDay': False, u'description': u'\r\n\tDavid Konisky\r\n\t\r\n\tExtreme Weather Exposure and Support for Climate Change Adaptation\r\n', u'startDate': u'12:00pm', u'calendarName': None, u'recurDateUtc': None, u'imageId': None, u'privateAndViewing': False, u'imageEventId': None, u'going': False, u'location': u'', u'imageCampus': u'BL', u'summary': u'PAPF and G&M Summer Research Workshop', u'recurs': False, u'id': u'13164381'}
```

Most of the info that pops up when you click *more* or the summary heading is included in the json.

To get the start time and summary:

```
for ev in r.json()["events"][0]["events"]:
    print(ev["startDate"])
    print ev["summary"]
```

That gives you:

```
Summer 2016: Withdrawal with Grade of W or F for First Six Week classes
8:00am
Exhibit: Student Reform Movements at IU
9:00am
EXHIBIT: "Indiana Folk Arts: 200 Years of Tradition and Innovation"
9:00am
EXHIBIT: "Stirring the Pot: Bringing the Wanamakers Home"
9:00am
EXHIBIT:  "Cherokee Craft, 1973"
9:00am
EXHIBIT: "MONSTERS!'
9:00am
EXHIBIT: "Tools of Travel"
9:00am
EXHIBIT: "Thoughts, Things, and Theories...What Is Culture?"
10:00am
New in the Galleries
12:00pm
PAPF and G&M Summer Research Workshop
```

Comment: Dude this is awesome! I was wondering how to go about using parameters but never understood it fully. Thank you for this answer!

Comment: No worries, if you view the request in developer tools, under the xhr tab you can see exactly what happens, if you want the next page you can pass 2 as the pageNum.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the source of the page, and in the plain HTML, there are 25 `<a>` elements that have an href attribute. These are the 25 links that your script is finding.

Also, I'm not sure which events on that page are the ones that you're actually looking for, but I'm gonna guess that many (if not all) of those urls that were printed out are not actually the events that you're looking for (more on this later).

The reason you're not finding the other links that you see when you go to the page in your browser, is because they are generated using JavaScript. BeautifulSoup only looks at the plain HTML, and doesn't run any JavaScript, as it's just a tool for analyzing and modifying static HTML or XML files. From [their documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

> Beautiful Soup is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and XML files. It works with your favorite parser to provide idiomatic ways of navigating, searching, and modifying the parse tree.

You need to either utilize something with a JavaScript engine to actually generate those elements, or find out where this page is pulling its event list from, and go there for your data.

You can try using a real browser with something like [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), which even lets you search through the DOM similarly to BeautifulSoup so you wouldn't need to use BeautifulSoup as well. If you're dead set on using BeautifulSoup, though, you can use Selenium to control a browser so it generates the elements using JavaScript (since that's what browsers do automatically), and then have Selenium just give you the source by calling something like this (`driver.page_source` will only get you what `requests` gave you):

```python
html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
```

There's also headless browsers ("headless" meaning that it doesn't have a GUI, so you'd never see it and it wouldn't need a display) that you could use if you'd prefer that, or your script needs to run on something without a display (I know that Firefox simply won't launch if you don't have a display connected). I'd imagine that there's a way to utilize BeautifulSoup with these browsers too, if you really want to.

If you decide to go the route where you look at where this page is pulling its event data from, you might be able to get away with just using `requests`, because if the JavaScript is just fetching some JSON file, `requests` has a `response.json()` function that will turn the whole thing into a python `dict`, and you can just search through that.

If you are using an HTML parser though(e.g. BeautifulSoup, Selenium), you should definitely try to narrow down where you're searching for these links by finding the element on the page that contains all these `<a>` elements, and then calling `.find_all("a", href=True)` (for BeautifulSoup) or `.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href]")` (for Selenium) on that element object (yes, you can do that, which is awesome!).

I'm not sure of the exact criteria of your assignment, so I have no idea if any of these options conflict with them. But I hope I at least pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: The criteria is pretty lenient. I wanted to use Python Requests to stay away from browsers and I thought Requests would even be better then Selenium with a headless browser (which I could be wrong). On the page there are events in a ul with the id 'mainEvents' but this ul does not show up when I get a response from my requests to the url given. This is why I decided to try and just grab all the links and see if I can sort them later. This is when I noticed I was not getting all the necessary ones. So you say that these links I am missing are generated by Javascript and requests could run it?

Comment: I think I will have to use Selenium to do this because I read that, "Requests is an http library. It cannot run javascript." So I will work out doing it with Selenium and PhantomJS so I do not have to worry about a browser GUI. Thank you for your help!

Comment: However, can you explain how you know that the other links are created using javascript and not the first 5 I get? The links I was trying to get were in the '<ul id="eventList" style="overflow:hidden;width:700px;"></ul>'.

Comment: No problem! Correct, `requests` couldn't run JavaScript, but if all those events are contained in some JSON file or returned by an API as JSON, then you could use `requests` to convert it really easily to a python `dict`.

Comment: As for how I figured your links were being generated, your code was right, but you only had the original static HTML to work with, so I verified that there were only 25 `<a>` elements with an `href` in the HTML. Then I went to the page in Chrome, and entered `document.querySelectorAll("a[href]")` into the console, but it found 130 `<a>` elements, which means that at 105 of them were being generated by JavaScript. And since you said you weren't getting all of the links, I knew the remaining ones must be getting generated by JavaScript .

Comment: Brilliant! I thought Selenium would be slow but with PhantomJS it is quite fast! Thank you for the help, @SalmonMode!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!